# Cannot convert all csv (pipe delimiter) to xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried writing my own VBA code, everything and all files work great. However, I do have these 4 files that are converted to respective columns but in the file explorer, it's not shown as an excel workbook.

I've tried using fileformat 51, which gave me the same result, so I'm not sure where have gone wrong, please assist. Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
Sub CSVtoXlsx()

Do While fname <> ""
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim mydata As String, temparray() As String, strdata() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    csvfilepath = csvfolder & fname
    
    Open csvfilepath For Binary As #1
    mydata = LOF(1)
    Get #1, , mydata
    Close #1
    
    strdata() = Split(mydata, vbCrLf)
    temparray() = Split(strdata(0), "|")
    
    ReDim arcol(0 To UBound(temparray))
    For i = 0 To UBound(temparray)
        arcol(i) = 2
    Next i
    
    With wb.Sheets(1).QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="text;" & csvfilepath, Destination:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("a1"))
    .Name = "formatted_data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType= xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = arcol
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    wb.SaveAs (xlsfolder & fname & ".xlsx"), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    
    fname = Dir
```

Comment: Please, post all your code. Where `xlsfolder` is declared and what value does it take? Then, do you want naming the saved excel workbook as the csv file  name, including its extension? When a piece of code does not work as you need, it is recommended to avoid using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, `On Error Resume Next` and so on. Let VBA telling to you if a problem exists...

Comment: Hi, sorry, I wanted to put but system says I have put in too much code.. and noted on avoid using those lines

anyways
Dim csvfolder As String, csvfilepath As String
Dim xlsfolder As String
Dim fname As String
Dim lnlastrow As Long
Dim ststring As String
Dim stsplit() As String
Dim wbook As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook

Comment: When run the code didn't it raise an error at line `.textfilepaesetype = xlDelimited`? It is a type there... It should be `.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited`... Are there in your not seen code `On Error Resume Next`? Otherwise, how to run the above code without any error?

Comment: There is no ```On Error Resume Next``` in my code, sorry the original code is in my other laptop. The code is indeed ```.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited```

Comment: Update: all my files now can convert, but the name is "(converted) testing.csv", is there any way I can rename it? either remove the ".csv" or change it to "(converted) testing.xlsx"?

Comment: Of course, it is. You should split the csv file name and use the first array element followed by `.xlsx`. I,ve just posted an answer, showing exactly how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to eliminate `csv` extension, please replace:

```
wb.SaveAs (xlsfolder & fname & ".xlsx"), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

with:

```
wb.SaveAs (xlsfolder & Split(fname, ".")(0) & ".xlsx"), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: Hey man, it works. Thanks a lot!